# Не работает отрисвка элементов при вызове glDrawElements() в QOpenGLWidget

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, qt5

Пишу приложение в которое на данный момент нужно интегрировать систему частиц. У меня есть подходящая вещица - Magic Particles от Astralax. Я портировал функционал этой библиотеки к себе но у меня не работает отрисовка финального результата. Я не понимаю в чем именно проблема. То ли у меня не работает контекст правильно, то ли я пропустил какой то шаг. Можете посмотреть и запустить проект сами. *метод m_paintDevice->update(); как раз вызывает glDrawElements и он отрабатывает но результат не виден. В чем может быть проблема?*

**Код на [GitHub](https://github.com/iMashine/MPGLES).**

**mainwidget.cpp**

```
void MainWidget::initializeGL()
{
    makeCurrent();
    initializeOpenGLFunctions();
    glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);

    m_paintDevice = new PaintDevice(this->width(), this->height());
    timer.start(12, this);
}

void MainWidget::timerEvent(QTimerEvent *e)
{
    m_paintDevice->update();
    update();
}

void MainWidget::paintGL()
{
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    m_paintDevice->paint();
    QCoreApplication::postEvent(this, new QEvent(QEvent::UpdateRequest));
}
```

**mp_wrap.cpp**

```
void MP_Device_WRAP::DrawVertices(int starting_index, int indexes_count, int max_vertices)
{
    MP_BUFFER_RAM *index_buffer_ram = (MP_BUFFER_RAM *)index_buffer;

#ifdef INDEX_BUFFER_32_WRAP
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, indexes_count, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, &(index_buffer_ram->buffer[starting_index * 4]));
#else
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, indexes_count, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, &(index_buffer_ram->buffer[starting_index * 2]));
#endif
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Я нашел решение - все было связанно с шейдером который поставлялся в комплекте, я начал колдовать с его настройками и у меня все заработало, точнее на данный момент у меня все зеленым цветом рисуется.

параметр gl_FragColor шейдера в системе задается как сумма цвета частицы и текстуры.

```
void main()
{
    vec4 color;
    vec4 arg1;
    vec4 arg2;
    vec4 colorTex;

    colorTex = texture2D(texture0, textureCoordinate0);
    arg1 = colorVarying;
    arg2 = colorTex;
    color = arg1 * arg2;
    gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    //gl_FragColor = color;
```

}

Закомментированная часть кода - дефолтная строка шейдера. Я заменил цвет для эксперимента и увидел отрисовывающиеся частицы. После этого (в течении нескольких дней) я завел и саму работу текстур, путем переноса всего функционала по работе с тектурами из враппера в QOpenGLTexture.

Это результат того что получилось после замены цвета в шейдере (точнее с установленным параметром gl_FragColor = colorVarying;

[image: 1]

После того как я завел работу текстуры и восстановил шейдер к исходным параметрам получился следующий результат:

[image: 2]

А финальный результат должен будет выглядеть вот так:

[image: 3]

Но на данный момент я испытываю трудности в конечной реализации такого эффекта. Связанно это либо с смешиванием, либо с некорректной работой цветовой схемы (альфа канал), но это уже не относится к данному посту. Спасибо.

Comment: Опишите в ответе детально какие настройки Вы поставили

Comment: Отписал, спасибо за помощь.